# How to run Xcode project on device with public beta

Tags: ios, xcode, beta

I’m trying to run my project on my iPhone, but it won’t let me because my phone is on the public beta, is there a way to run this without having to get beta software for Xcode as well?
I’m currently running iOS 13.6 and Xcode only allows up to 13.5

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to run a project on a device with newer iOS than iOS SDK included in Xcode

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the appropriate Xcode beta release that came out with the iOS version you're running on your device.